# Auto numbering Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-data-validation

I want to have auto numbering dependent on cell drop down box in helper column so i can sorted out.

If someone pick `Start` in `A2` to have number 1 in `B2`.
Then if they skip one or two and chose `Start` `A4` in `B3=2`,
`A6` in `B6=3`
`A3` in `B3=4`
Then auto sort the sheet based on `B` column?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hu-NQ3QpeP-_SMwiSm3EY4uyVS36cswYrInOwgy7oP0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: _"A4=2 in B3, A6=3 in B6 A3=4 in B3"_ ???? I am lost. Could you please give the expected result as an example on the sheet?

Comment: sheet 1 is now example

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula in cell B2:

```
=ArrayFormula( IF(A2:A15="Start",row(A2:A15)-1,""))
```

We make use of the function ROW. ROW returns the row number of a specified cell..
Please read more about ROW [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316?hl=en-GB)

Comment: I dont want to count rows but sequence when "Start" is inishiated in row A